# how design for table that has about 50 column and select user desired column

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I have table that has 50 column(there isn't any oneToMany relation in it). when admin want to add new row for about 20 columns of this table he can decide which column to show in user side for example:

table has columns: description, address, dateOfConstruct, dateOfRebuild, stars...

in admin panel user can fill mentioned input and each of them has check box that if checked that field can be must shown on user site.

How can I design this? and how should I do select query in user side?

Comment: It means Table structure is skrewed .You need to redisign it . :)

Comment: And we dont know 50 fields . If you give us then only we can help you! Thanks

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com table field that I need that features for them are something like these: description, address, dateOfConstruct, dateOfRebuild, stars..

Answer (score 0):

This is an application problem, not a database problem.

Have the app should construct the `SELECT` statement based on what the user specifies in the UI.

Comment: user(admin) specifies what column to be shown in admin panel and it will represent in front-end for all users.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do something like

```
SELECT $column1, $column2, $column3
FROM ...
```

of course after validating input, etc. and select only what is necessary and then only display what you have got from the db.

However, if this is not going to cause too much load on the DB I would select everything and show/hide columns depending on what user have selected. A little bit hakish, but it will do the job.